# Horizontal alignment for title, frametitle, and text

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I am creating a fairly minimalist custom theme for myself and want to have everything on the title frame be correctly centered, frame titles to be close to the left border, but the left margin for text to be quite wide. My problem is that using `\setbeamersize` to get wide margins for the text will also move everything on the title frame and put it off center, as in the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=5cm}
\title{Title should be Centered}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Frametitle should be here}
\lipsum
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of MWE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick hack: temporarily change the `hoffset` for the title page

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=5cm}
\title{Title should be Centered}

\begin{document}

{
    \hoffset=-2cm
    \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{Frametitle should be here}
\lipsum
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]